# How to set ellipses to the end of TextView?

Tags: android, textview

In my application I want use `TextView` and I want when this `TextView` if get l line show **3dos (...)** 
**I write this lines in TextView :**

```
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxLines="1"
```

But always **set ...** end of `textView`.

**But I want if line after 1 lines then show ...**

how can I it?

Comment: yours question is awful. do you want to add "..." to the end of the string?

Comment: @DroiDev, yes my friend. but I want first set maxLines 1 , if lines > 1 then show "..."  . I write above codes but show "..." always. I want if lines > 1 show "..."     .  can you help me? please

Comment: you cant check for number of lines. you can however check for number of characters in the string and then go from there.

Comment: @DroiDev, can you send to me code?

Comment: i lied. hold on.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code :

```
    if (holder.newsTitle.getLineCount() > 1) {
        holder.newsTitle.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
    }
```

I hope help you dear

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the number of lines of a TextView, you can do this...

```
textView.setText("Here is my text");
int numOfLines = textView.getLineCount();

if (numOfLines > 1) {
    //code here
}
```

The BEST way to do this is by character count.

```
theString = "This is my string";

if (theString.length() > 5) {
    textView.setText(theString.substring(0, 5) + "...");
}
```

The above code will say, if the character count is greater than 5, cut off the characters after 5 and add ...
The above code prints out:

> This ...